# Сайт дважды отдаёт одну и ту же страницу, без видимых на то причин

Tags: битрикс, header, php, javascript

Добрый день!

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: сайт, который я разрабатываю отдаёт одну и ту же страницу дважды, т.е. в Firebug я вижу вот такую вот штуку (это я один раз зашёл на страницу "Акции"):

[image]

Я сравнил заголовки первого и второго запросов. Разница в параметре Accept:

Первый запрос
**Accept    text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8**

Второй запрос
**Accept    image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5**

Как будто он догружает какую-то картинку. Об этом также может говорить и парамерт - DataSize  разница ничтожна, но есть:

[image]

На всякий случай сравнил ответы этих двух запросов (вкладка Response в параметрах запроса), все русские буквы в первом запросе выдаются иероглифами:

[image]

Каких-то явных ошибок в коде я не вижу, Firebug, WebDEveloper не ругается на отсутствие (или неправильные пути) картинок и других ресурсов страницы. Консоль Google Chrome также ни на что не ругается.

Ошибка пропадает (т.е. страница перестаёт вызываться дважды), если в вёрстке закомментировать один из контейнеров DIV, в который подгружается контентная часть. Я перепроверил все css стили и js скрипты, связанные с этим DIV, ничего подозрительного не нашёл (стилей нет, скрипты JS комментировал, ошибка остаётся).

В чём ошибка, как найти, подскажите! Заранее спасибо!

P.S. Сайт работает на 1С Битрикс 14.5 в кодировке UTF-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Для того чтобы администратор мог менять фон на галавной странице, не залезая в код, я сделал следующий механизм. В настройках инфоблока "Слайдер на галавной" добавил необходиоме изображение, а в **component_epilog.php** компонента **news.list** (который выполнял роль слайдера на главной) я достал из инфоблока нужную мне картинку и поместил её адрес в свойство страницы через **$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty();**. Позже в коде шаблона header.php я подставил это свойство в дополнительный css класс.

```
background-image:url(<? $APPLICATION->ShowProperty("main-wrapper-bg");?>)!important;
```

Проблема в том, что я ошибочно поставил этот стиль общему классу wrapper а не конкретному классу главной страницы wrapper_main_page, в результате  ShowProperty() подставлял в стиль пустоту, что в сочетании с отработкой эпилога Bitrix запрашивала страницу повторно.

Решение: я просто указал правильный класс, встречающийся только на главной странице сайта.